# How to get an array list and copy elements to a new list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Here is what I have to do:

Instantiates a new list array and copies the elements of the existing list array to the new list array. The list array instance variable becomes a pointer to the new list array.

I am working with array lists and methods. I have an array list with some numbers. I took numbers from that list but I don't know how to put the numbers that I took into a new array list.

Comment: Are you using ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

HI Please check the below code.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> oldlist = new ArrayList<>();
    oldlist.add(0);
    oldlist.add(1);
    oldlist.add(2);
    oldlist.add(3);

    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    newList.addAll(oldlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic problem in programming. It is usually called "iterating" or more specifically here: "iterating through / over a collection".

A classic way in Java would be:

```
ArrayList<Stuff> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (Stuff thing : list1) list2.add(thing);
```

You can read the second line as: "For each thing, of class Stuff, in list1, do..." The thing you want to do, is calling `add`on the second list.

As of Java7 you could do:

```
 list1.forEach((thing) -> list2.add(thing));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
```

Comment: Wow... why downvote? At least a comment would be nice... I use this hundred times in my apps. Works fine. What is wrong with that?